# two arrays, group second array based on repetitive values of first and form a string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have two arrays and a string as shown below

```
var str=offer?;

var names = [channelId, channelId, offerType, offerType, Language];

var values =[647, 763, international, programming, English];
```

Both arrays will be of same size.

I need to form a string such that

```
final string = offer?channelId=647,763&offerType=international,programming&language=English
```

I need this to be done in JavaScript.

I tried it this was:

```
   var namesMatched=false;
   for(var i=0; i<names.lengthl; i++){
      for(var j=i+1; j<names.length; j++){
       if(names[i]==names[j]){
         str=str+names[i]+"="+values[i]+","+values[j];
         namesMatched=true;
         continue;
       }
       else if(namesMatched){
          str=str+"&";
          i=names.length-j;
       }
       else{
         str=str+names[i]+"="+values[i]+"&";
         break;
       }
      }
    }
```

But i'm not getting as expected.

Any help here is appreciated.

Comment: Are those supposed to be arrays of strings, or are all of those values defined somewhere?

Comment: Is it guaranteed that identical names will be next to each other in the `names` array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my solution, you don't need two for sentences:

```
var str='offer?';

        var names = ['channelId', 'channelId', 'offerType', 'offerType', 'Language'];

    var values =[647, 763, 'international', 'programming', 'English'];

var last = '';

for (var i=0; i<names.length; i++) {
  var name = names[i];
  if (last === name) {
    str+=','+values[i];
  } else {
      if (i !== 0) {
        str+='&';
      }
    str+=name+'='+values[i];
  }
  last = name;

}

console.log(str);
```

http://jsbin.com/kinefipalu/edit?html,js,output

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer, because it makes the assumption that identical names come next to each other in the `names` array, which should not necessarily have to be the case.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I based my solution on the fact that "Both arrays will be of same size.", which the OP stated. I mistakenly assumed the pairing of both values to be in the correct order. I hope OP can shed some light on this.

Comment: Also, in his example code it is obvious that the pairing is correct.

Comment: I've posted a comment to the question so we'll see what he says. Yes, his example shows identical names next to each other. However, it does not follow that it is guaranteed that that is always going to be the case, or that a good solution should assume that it will be.

Comment: I agree with you. However, since having two completely separate arrays it is virtually impossible to join them in any other way, since there are no references between them. The comment you've written under my solution applies to both other solutions as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use (explanatory comments inline)

```
var str='offer?';
var names = ['channelId', 'channelId', 'offerType', 'offerType', 'Language'];
var values = [647, 763, 'international', 'programming', 'English'];

var temp = names.reduce(function (a, b, i) {
    // add an array object for each name if it doesn't alreay exist
    a[names[i]] = (a[names[i]] || [])
    // push the value onto the arra
    a[names[i]].push(values[i])
    return a;
}, {})

// loopt through the properties of the temporary object (a collection of value arrays tagged by name)
var output = str + Object.keys(temp).map(function (e) {
    // construct the substring for each key
    return e + '=' + temp[e].join(',');
// join the substrings using &
}).join('&')

console.log(output)
```

---

**Steps**

1. You first use `reduce` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce to consolidate the 2 arrays into a single object (`temp`). Each unique name will be a property on the object and the value will be an array of values that are tagged to that name.
2. You use `Object.keys()` to get all the keys (names) in the temporary object https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys
3. You use `map` to convert the names and their corresponding value arrays to a substring https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map
4. You then use `join` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join to join all these substrings together

---

```js
var str='offer?';
var names = ['channelId', 'channelId', 'offerType', 'offerType', 'Language'];
var values = [647, 763, 'international', 'programming', 'English'];

var temp = names.reduce(function (a, b, i) {
  // add an array object for each name if it doesn't alreay exist
  a[names[i]] = (a[names[i]] || [])
  // push the value onto the arra
  a[names[i]].push(values[i])
  return a;
}, {})

// loopt through the properties of the temporary object (a collection of value arrays tagged by name)
var output = str + Object.keys(temp).map(function (e) {
  // construct the substring for each key
  return e + '=' + temp[e].join(',');
  // join the substrings using &
}).join('&')

alert(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're OK with using Underscore, you can group the values with

```
groups = _.groupBy(values, function(val, i) { return names[i]; });
```

In other words, group the values by the name found in the corresponding position in the `names` array. That will give you

```
{ channelId: [647, 763], ... }
```

You can turn that into your final string easily enough with

```
_.map(groups, function(val, key) { return key + '=' + val; }) . join('&');
```

Note in the above line that `val`, which is an array, when coerced to a string automatically joins its elements with a comma.

Or, depending on your preferred programming style:

```
function name(val, i)  { return names[i]; }
function key(val, key) { return key + '=' + val; }

_.map(_.groupBy(values, name), key) . join('&')
```

or with chaining

```
_.chain(values) . groupBy(name) . map(key) . join('&') . value()
```